# Book about portals and pyramids

Tags: story-identification, novel, teleportation, wormhole

I believe I got this from the library about 10 years ago. The novel had two men, possibly brothers or professor and student, and one woman who becomes romantically involved with the younger one. I think the men were supposed to be archeologists or historians or the like. The 2 men while exploring in a jungle encounter an old pyramid. They end up walking through a doorway which leads to a completely different pyramid and location on earth. At some point they meet the woman and are running from mysterious people out to kill them. Research helps them go to another pyramid and that one leads to or is in the Nevada desert I think. It’s a new structure and definitely associated with the bad guys. Somehow they get in and notice the doors hermetically seal. They accidentally activate the portal in the new Nevada pyramid structure and end up on the moon in a deep shadow of a crater which explains why nobody using telescopes would see anything. Air was slowly leaking and they figured out how to return. At the end, at one of the pyramids there was a volcano nearby and I think it factors in to their escape but the older man dies. I am not sure on that point though.

I have been trying to find it but all of my searches with combinations of pyramid, portal, doorway, teleport and moon are failing me. I must have something off but this is the best I remember. The book implied that the portals were naturally occurring and that the pyramids were made in those locations because they helped lock the portals/doorways or concentrated the length they would remain open or something. The people who had originally made and used the pyramids wound up on different continents which explained why pyramids were all over the world but rare.

Edit: Here’s a bit more I remember. I think the first pyramid was Mayan. The only location not on Earth that I remember was the moon. There was a discussion regarding what to call the doorway portals in the book. Not teleport and I don’t think they went with portal either. They decided on doorways or windows or something else plain. The villains were a mystery but smacked of black ops.

I think that possibly at the end either the older man or another person was an alien stuck on Earth who just wanted to tweak/use the doorway to go home. Really not sure on this last point though

Comment: This sounds very familiar... except that my brain is associating it with pillars instead of pyramids. And, if it's the same one, there's a twist where it turns out that one of the men was originally from the other world, and had some sort of a medallion that was from there, and also what allowed them to access the portals.

Comment: Pillars could be correct. I remembered it as a doorway inside the pyramids but perhaps it’s  ruins with pillars because now I recall something vaguely about the medallion.

Comment: I don’t remember anything about asteroids or underground cities. That question didn’t feel connected.

Comment: I did read this. It'll probably come to me in the middle of the night. For some reason I keep thinking about Atlantis.

Answer (score 2):

Might this be *[The Stonehenge Gate](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/11975.The_Stonehenge_Gate)* by Jack Williamson?

[image: Front cover of The Stonehenge Gate]

> In a basement in New Mexico, four poker buddies and amateur adventurers who have discovered a dark mystery buried beneath the sands of the Sahara desert decide to do something about it.
>
> In the deep Sahara, they find an ancient artifact that will change their lives and the world, forever… a gateway between planets that links Earth to distant worlds where they discover wonders and terrors beyond their wildest imagination.
>
> Jack Williamson, the dean of science fiction writers, masterfully weaves an exciting tale that takes the friends to the far corners of the universe. While one leads an oppressed people towards freedom, another uncovers clues that could identify a long-dormant super-advanced civilization of immortal beings, and the key to the origin of life on Earth.

Comment: Not sure. My library had a digital copy though and I have checked it out. I’ll come back and check your answer if that’s the right book

Comment: Good guess it that wasn’t the book. Similar in a few major points but very different. I waited until chapter 20 to be sure but this definitely not the one I am thinking of.